# HTML/CSS - Scroll snap after first item, continue scrolling regularly after

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, scrollbar

I have a horizontal scrolling box with two items split down the middle. The first item is a large `div`. I'm trying to get the scrolling to snap at the end of the first item, and then scroll regularly on the second `div` and its overflowing content. [Here is a CodePen demonstrating my current setup](https://codepen.io/kylehorkley/pen/Rwoeqem?editors=1100).

The HTML:

```
<div class="snap-row">
    <div class="snap-section large"></div>
    <div class="snap-section">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.snap-row {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    scroll-padding: 32px;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    width: 100%;
}

.snap-section {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    width: 50%;
}

.snap-section.large {
    background: blue;
}

.items {
    background: chartreuse;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 0 32px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css:

```
.snap-section.large {
background: blue;
scroll-snap-align: start;}
```

This is to keep the large element visible, wait for the scroll.

```
.item {
    scroll-snap-align: start;}
```

This is to keep small elements visible when the user scroll, otherwise it will snap back to the large element.
It should work now.

Comment: This is good for having the items snap scroll, but what if you want the items to scroll freely? So that the first `snap-section` is the only thing that snaps?

Comment: @KyleHorkley did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @PeterW Unfortunately I did not :(